# How to split objects to new layer in a image automatically in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I want to create a layer for each animal in the below image. my approach is by lasso tool selecting each animal then cut and paste it. This cause new layer is created. I want to know that is there any option in Photoshop to do it automatically?

[image]

Comment: There's no option to do it automatically.  Photoshop can't see and doesn't know anything about how to separate objects. Perhaps a script that can employ some kind of AI could do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a script for that — [Split Layer to Islands](https://scriptorator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layerstoislands/index.html) — it's a part of a free scripts pack [Scriptorator](https://gumroad.com/l/scriptorator):

[image]

Note that in your file assets seem to be quite close to each other so maybe you'd require to upscale the image to `400%` or `800%` using the `Nearest Neighbour` sampling method before splitting the layers. Then you can resize it back using the same method to keep the pixels intact:

- My test file:

[image]

- Resizing to 800% using the `Nearest Neighbour`:

[image]

- After running the script and resizing the image back to original the image looks the same but layers are separated:

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice Sergey

Answer (score 1):

As already said by others Photoshop has no function like "decide and make a new selection which contains the next object in this single layer bitmap image"

But you can generate a script or even record an action which lets you to click the next shape and after it does the rest for you. You click a shape and press a function key to run your action. I tried the action recording for this.

You can select a shape against transparent background with the magic wand which has tolerance=255. The action cuts the selection, pastes it, moves the appeared new layer to the bottom in the layers panel, reselects the top layer and that's that. The action stops and lets you select with the magic wand the next shape. You press the starting key to process it.

In the next image shape A is clicked with the magic wand:

[image]

Pressing function key F3 runs my action "separate" which moves the selected shape to the bottom layer. After running it and making 3 more selection+runs I got the next result:

[image]

The shapes accumulate to the center because the shapes are pasted, not pasted in place.